# Passing a function to the jquery On event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

This works:

```
$(".logo").click(doSomething)
```

This does not:

```
$('.popular').on '.logo', 'click', doSomething
```

---

I need the latter because some `.logo` elements are loaded using AJAX after the page is done loading.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: For one thing, rename `topServiceClicked` to `doSomething` (and make sure `.logo` will come somewhere inside `.popular`). Also, argument order is wrong: `.on(eventnames, selector, handler)`, unless you are expecting an event called `.logo` on a `<click>` element. :)

Comment: `$('.popular').on('click', '.logo', topServiceClicked/doSomething)`

Comment: I forgot to rename the function. Edited.

Comment: @Thanks Rayon if you leave your answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
$('.popular').on('click','.logo', function() {
// do something
 topServiceClicked();});
```